# Let $f: (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue integrable. Prove that $\forall x > 0 \ F_x(t) = f(t)e^{-xt}$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

My attempt:

Let $x>0$. Define $h_n(t) = |f(t)|(1+\frac{xt}{n})^{-n}$. Now, since $x,t >0$, $|f(t)| \geq h_n \geq 0 \ \forall n \ $, and since $h_n \to |f(t)|e^{-xt}$, by the dominated convergence theorem ($f$ is integrable), then $|f(t)|e^{-xt}$ is also integrable.

Now, i'm also asked to prove that the function $g: (0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}, \  g(x) = \displaystyle \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(t)e^{-xt}$ is continuous. However i'm not sure how to approach this. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Why not just use that fact that $e^{-xt} \le 1$?

Comment: Use the dominated convergence theorem to prove that if $x_n\to x$ then $g(x_n)\to g(x)$, then invoke the sequential criterion theorem (i.e. the sequential definition of continuity).

Comment: I'm assuming by "Lebesgue integrable" you mean that the integral is finite?

Comment: Thanks @User8128, that was it. Also, yeah, I'm not sure why I even went down the path of using dominated convergence to show that $F_x(t)$ was integrable

Comment: @Math1000 yes, that's what I meant.